# How to delete many NotePad files quickly?

Tags: notepad

I am trying to find out if there is a fast way to delete several (>10) Notepad files at the same time without going through the open file, delete file routine for each Notepad file? I am running Vista Home Premium
Thank you.

Comment: The content (emptying the file), or the entire file (delete it from the harddrive)?

Answer (score 3):

What about selecting all the text files in the directory and using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> keys

Answer (score 3):

Open the folder that contains your "several Notepad files" (.txt I suppose), hold down the CTRL key and highlight each file you want to delete with a single left click. When done, hit DEL (or Shift + DEL to bypass the Recycle Bin).

Comment: +1 Or use SHIFT + click to select a consecutive block.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the structure of the folder, but you could show DETAILS view, sort by (file) TYPE. Now all the .txt files are together and you can click the first, then SHIFT + click the last. All .txt files are now selected and just hit delete.